# DevExpress download link

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Last 3 days on words I was trying to download "DevExpress 13.1.4 " Still I haven't get ,
Could you please anybody provide "DevExpress 13.1.14" trail version download link

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Trial installers for previous versions are not available. You can only download the most recent version (current 15.2.7).

Answer (score -1):

You can download Devexpress from [here](https://downloaddevtools.com/en/product/124/download-devexpress-net-components-with-crack)